# Cordova FCM - delay ios notfication permission pop up

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm plugin and it works great for both platforms.

However, on iOS, the notification permission pop up is invoked right at the launch of the app, and I want it to appear only after the login process is complete.

I have zero knowledge in objective-C so i can't override the classes.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in case anyone encounters the same problem in the future...

https://github.com/jjrom/cordova-plugin-fcm/commit/4fedc72b2d94d85a67f6266aef13e774b7a16bfe